# download all files from S3 and upload them in same folder

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have enabled versioning on the bucket whenever a new bucket is created. But for backward compatibility (buckets which are already created), i'm downloading all files/keys and uploading again. I'm doing this:

```
fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
```

But i am not able to figure out while uploading how to upload file in their specific folder. Or is there another solution to fix backward compatibility.

Comment: do you mean whenever a update of object is pushed to the bucket, you keep the previous ones as well?

Comment: something like that. because earlier i have not enabled versioning, so i have created multiple S3 bucket without versioning, but now i am enabling versioning so for the newly created buckets it works fine, But for old bucket the value of versions of keys will be null, so to have backward compatibility i was thinking to download entire bucket and re-upload it. so that i can i have at-least one version for each file

Answer (score 1):

S3 doesn't really have folders, it "fakes" it with logic that looks for common prefixes separated by "/". The "key" is the full path name of the file within the bucket.

It sounds like you are doing a get and then want to do a put of the same bytes to the same key in the bucket. If that is what you want to do, then just use the same key that you used for getting the object.

In a bucket that has versioning turned on, this will result in two copies of the file. It is not clear why you would want to do that (assuming that you are writing back exactly what you are reading). Wouldn't you just end up paying for two copies of the same file?

My understanding is that if you turn on versioning for a bucket that already has files in it, that everything works the way you would expect. If a pre-existing file gets deleted, it just adds a delete marker. If a pre-existing file gets overwritten, it keeps the prior version (as a prior version of the new file). There is no need to pro-actively rewrite existing files when you turn on versioning. If you are concerned, you can easily test this through either the S3 Console, the command line interface, or through one of the language-specific APIs.

Comment: enabling versions is for back-up of file, and also if i'm editing a file uploaded to S3 then i will not have access for the previous file.

Comment: yes your right no need to pro-actively rewrite. I will test all possible scenario.

Comment: if i deleted a file from folder, but later i realized i wanted that file, so in this case i will have to do. Because if i will re-upload it once again even if i delete the latest file i will have the versioned copy.

Comment: @dharmeshmehta When versioning is turned on, deleting a file keeps the existing file and creates a new version that is a "delete marker." When you do normal access to the bucket, the delete marker causes the key to not show up. When you access the bucket for specific versions, you can see the old version as well as the delete marker; in this mode, you can delete the delete marker and the original file becomes visible again.